# Cannot add foreign key constraint - data types match

Tags: mysql, sql, constraints, alter-table

i am trying to do alter like this

```
alter table user_position 
add constraint fk_user_position_user 
foreign key (id_user)
references users(id_user),
add constraint fk_user_position_waypoint 
foreign key (id_waypoint)
references waypoint(id_waypoint);
```

But i get this error:`Error Code: 1215. Cannot add foreign key constraint`

I check columns data types and they all match -

- users.id_user int(11)= user_position.id_user int(11)
- waypoint.id_waypoint int(11)=user_position.id_waypoint int(11)

I´m getting this error on both alters separatelly when i try it

I am running on MySql database, command executed in MySql Workbench

```
DDL for all tables:

    /*
Created     29. 7. 2013
Modified        30. 7. 2013
Project     
Model       
Company     
Author      
Version     
Database        mySQL 5 
*/


Create table Users (
    id_user Int NOT NULL,
    username Char(20),
    pass Char(20),
 Primary Key (id_user)) ENGINE = MyISAM;

Create table Waypoint (
    id_waypoint Int NOT NULL,
    id_user Int NOT NULL,
    name Char(20),
    description Char(20),
    priority Int,
    type_number Int,
 Primary Key (id_waypoint,id_user)) ENGINE = MyISAM;

Create table Message (
    text Text,
    id_message_type Int NOT NULL,
    shown Bool,
    id_message Int NOT NULL,
    id_user Int NOT NULL,
 Primary Key (id_message_type,id_message,id_user)) ENGINE = MyISAM;

Create table Message_Type (
    id_message_type Int NOT NULL,
    description Char(20),
 Primary Key (id_message_type)) ENGINE = MyISAM;

Create table User_group (
    id_user_group Int NOT NULL,
    description Char(20),
    id_user_rights Char(20) NOT NULL,
 Primary Key (id_user_group,id_user_rights)) ENGINE = MyISAM;

Create table User_Rights (
    id_user_rights Char(20) NOT NULL,
    description Char(20),
    kod Char(20),
 Primary Key (id_user_rights)) ENGINE = MyISAM;

Create table Permisions (
    id_permision Char(20) NOT NULL,
    description Char(20),
 Primary Key (id_permision)) ENGINE = MyISAM;

Create table UserRightPermisions (
    id_user_rights Char(20) NOT NULL,
    id_permision Char(20) NOT NULL,
 Primary Key (id_permision)) ENGINE = MyISAM;

Create table User_Set_Of_Groups (
    id_user_group Int NOT NULL,
    id_user_rights Char(20) NOT NULL,
    id_user Int NOT NULL,
    is_main Bool,
 Primary Key (id_user_group,id_user_rights,id_user)) ENGINE = MyISAM;


Alter table Waypoint add Foreign Key (id_user) references Users (id_user) on delete  restrict on update  restrict;
Alter table Message add Foreign Key (id_user) references Users (id_user) on delete  restrict on update  restrict;
Alter table User_Set_Of_Groups add Foreign Key (id_user) references Users (id_user) on delete  restrict on update  restrict;
Alter table Message add Foreign Key (id_message_type) references Message_Type (id_message_type) on delete  restrict on update  restrict;
Alter table User_Set_Of_Groups add Foreign Key (id_user_group,id_user_rights) references User_group (id_user_group,id_user_rights) on delete  restrict on update  restrict;
Alter table User_group add Foreign Key (id_user_rights) references User_Rights (id_user_rights) on delete  restrict on update  restrict;
Alter table UserRightPermisions add Foreign Key (id_user_rights) references User_Rights (id_user_rights) on delete  restrict on update  restrict;
Alter table UserRightPermisions add Foreign Key (id_permision) references Permisions (id_permision) on delete  restrict on update  restrict;
```

Comment: You should post the actual table definitions of all involved tables. Otherwise the comments are basically going to be "are you sure? double-check"

Comment: Maybe your user_position table has values in those fields that are not in the reference tables.

Comment: Does the existing data violate the constraint?

Answer (score 0):

- The foreign key must refer to the primary (or unique) key
- The columns data types must be exactly the same (check NOT NULL, UNSIGNED etc)

Comment: MySQL documentation says that "InnoDB allows a foreign key constraint to reference a non-unique key. This is an InnoDB extension to standard SQL."  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html

Comment: Foregin keys can be null